# time card code python practice problem regarding while loops

Tags: python-3.x

Writing a code that keeps track of when an employee punches in for work and I am running into a little of an issue. The code is as follows:

```
 emp_no = ""
 parts = ""

while emp_no!="": *(This does NOT run correctly as currently constructed. However when you replace it with while emp_no!="sentinel", it runs correctly, this while loop is where I am having trouble.)

    v= False
    emp_no = input("enter emp_no (ddd-dd-dddd): ")
    parts = emp_no.split('-')

    if len(parts) == 3:
          if len(parts[0])==3 and len(parts[1])==2 and len(parts[2])==4:
              if parts[0].isdigit() and parts[1].isdigit() and parts[2].isdigit():
                  v= True
        print(v)
```

the employee will enter there employee id number and if entered correctly the program checks them in. If entered incorrectly the program will say the id entered is False and will have them enter the number again. If anyone could help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It cannot run as the initial value already invalidate the condition

```
parts = ""

while True:

    emp_no = input("enter emp_no (ddd-dd-dddd): ")
    parts = emp_no.split('-')

    if len(parts) == 3:
        try:
            # this will convert each value to an integer. If any parts is not an int, ValueError will be raised
            parts = [int(part) for part in parts]
            print(True)
        except ValueError:
            print(False)
    elif emp_no == "":
        # exit the while loop
        break
```